# How to get a dictionary value in plan string associated with same key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pytest

i have dictionary as input an input like

**Input dictionary :**

```
{'location': {'street1': 'Deborah Throughway', 'city': 'East Betty', 'stateOrProvince': 'AK', 'postcode': '50545', 'country': 'US'}}
```

and **expected output is:**

```
'SiteAddress': 'Deborah Throughway, East Betty, AK, US, 50545'
```

I tried `list(dictionary['location'].values())` but getting

```
{'SiteAddress': ['Deborah Throughway', 'East Betty', 'AK', '50545', 'US'] }
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong and how we can get expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = {'location': {'street1': 'Deborah Throughway', 'city': 'East Betty', 'stateOrProvince': 'AK', 'postcode': '50545', 'country': 'US'}}

def main():
    loc = data['location']
    address = ",".join([loc['street1'], loc['city'], loc['stateOrProvince'], loc['country'], loc['postcode']])

    print("SiteAddress: {0}".format(address))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
SiteAddress: Deborah Throughway,East Betty,AK,US,50545
```

Comment: supossed you need a fixed order, without order its easier